# Design Fluid Body Sections Layout?

Tags: css, layout, fluid

Does anyone know what code/method should I use to achieve this kind of layouts?

1. How to layout the body as different sections
2. How to wrap each body section and make it fluid

Somewhat like each section of the body is fluid? 
Are these examples even considered fluid body sections?

When I view on my 22 inch monitor the images and site width spans out all the way to the edge of my screen, and on ipad and iphone it's also the same but has less white space on the edges due to smaller screen.

Examples:

http://www.linkedinfluence.com/

https://getmyo.com/

Thank you very much

Comment: did you ever try to search "fluid layout" or even better "responsive layout" on google?? or even here in stackoverflow?? there are plenty of tutorials, frameworks, templates and so on. do a search before asking.

Answer (score 0):

Twitter Bootstrap has solid Fluid Layout potential, pretty easy to pick up as well. It also takes advantage of Media Queries for responsive design.

Take a look at the Fluid Grid System documentation here:
http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/scaffolding.html#fluidGridSystem